# why mysql prefer to scan the table rather than using composite index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have this table :

business:

```
bussId | x | y | bussStatus |
```

I want to run this query :

```
SELECT * FROM bussiness  WHERE  (bussiness.x BETWEEN 31.214857 AND 31.658529) AND (bussiness.y BETWEEN  34.502798 AND 34.918799) AND bussId > 500 AND bussStatus >0
```

EXPLAIN query return this result :

```
Id : 1
select_type : SIMPLE
table : bussiness
type : range
possible_keys : PRIMARY,bussStatus,xy,bussId_xy_status
key : PRIMARY
key_len : 4
ref : NULL
rows : 134680
Extra : Using where
```

this shows that mysql choose to use the `PRIMARY` key although there is a composite index `bussId_xy_status` that can sort x , y  , status and bussId !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM business b
WHERE (b.x BETWEEN 31.214857 AND 31.658529) AND
      (b.y BETWEEN 34.502798 AND 34.918799) AND
      b.bussId > 500 AND
      b.bussStatus > 0;
```

All of the comparisons in the `WHERE` clause are inequalities.  This means that a composite index is of very limited use -- only the first column in the index can be used most effectively.  The optimizer has decided that a full table scan using the primary key is most effective, probably because of the condition on `bussid`.  MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) has a good review of composite indexes and how they are used.

If you need to do these types of geographic comparisons, you might consider a spatial index -- see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html).

EDIT:

Bummer.  The MySQL documentation that I referenced doesn't do quite as good a job as it should on explaining multi-column indexes.  Indexes basically provide two access functions:  index lookups and index scans.  A lookup allows the index to go to just the right set of values.  An index scan allows the index to identify all rows between two values.  (The most common type of index is a B-tree index which supports both these operations.)

Consider a table t with an index on `(a, b, c)`.  The index can be used for a `where` clause when all the comparisons are connected by AND and at least one is on `a`.  So, the index can be used for:

```
where a = 'xyz'
where a > 'xyz'
where a in ('xyz', 'tbd')
```

The first is equality.  The second two are inequality, because a single index lookup is not sufficient.

The index cannot (in general) be used for:

```
where b = 'xyz'
where a = 'xyz' or b = 'xyz'
```

What happens when a second column is introduced?

```
where a = 'xyz' and b = 'abc'
where a > 'xyz' and b = 'abc'
where a in ('xyz', 'tbd') and b = 'abc'
```

The index can be fully utilized for the first case.  For the second two, only the "a" part of the index gets used, if at all.  The optimizer may decide to not use the index at all, because the first part chooses too many rows.

The general rule can be described as follows.  A multi-column index can be used for a `where` clause with the following conditions:

- All comparisons in the `where` clause are connected by AND.
- For the first "n" keys in the index ("left prefix"), the comparison is equality (that is `=` or `IS NULL`).
- Any comparison is allowed for the n + 1 key
- "n" can equal zero

The index cannot help with any subsequent comparisons after "n + 1" keys.  It can help in another way, which is as a covering index, but that is a separate topic.

In your case, all comparisons are inequalities, so "n" is 0.  Only the first key in the index can be used effectively, and the optimizer has decided that this is not selective enough to be efficient.

Also note that the index is not used whenever there is a function on a column.  This is not an issue in your case, but something as simple as:  `a + 0 = 0` *can* prevent the use of an index (I think this particular example might work differently in different databases).

Comment: thank you for your answer, the composite index reference that you provide doesn't explain why the composite index is not use full at my situation , could you please provide more explanation !

Comment: @OP, he has explained it. The first column of the index is used for `b.bussId > 500` and this does not allow using any more columns of the index to narrow down with the other conditions. If you had `b.busid= 500`, the next column could be used.